# Laravel: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 solution

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Why does this query result in an SQLSTATE error?

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'database.events.date' isn't in GROUP BY`

```
select `events`.`listing_id`, `events`.`date`, `events`.`listing_name`, count(*) as number_sold 
from `events` 
where `events`.`date` >= "2020-07-14" 
group by `events`.`listing_id` 
order by `events`.`date` asc
```

The query executes without error when I run it manually on the server, and with the expected results.

What specifically is the syntax error and why?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of your purpose would all be helpful here.

Comment: It tells you that columns in the list after `SELECT` must either be in the `GROUP BY` clause or a parameter to an aggregation function. `events.date` is listed after `SELECT` without an aggregation function but not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly taken from [Solve Query Failures Regarding ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL Mode](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/). A superb article.

**Explanation**

As of MySQL 5.7 they have made the syntax stricter to stop semantically incorrect queries from running. One particular new rule is called `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and it stops you from making errors when using the GROUP BY clause.

As easy example to understand is this:

Let's say we want to count the most popular pages on a website from this table:

```
+----+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id | page_url           | user_id | ts                  |
+----+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | /index.html        |       1 | 2019-04-17 12:21:32 |
|  2 | /index.html        |       2 | 2019-04-17 12:21:35 |
|  3 | /news.php          |       1 | 2019-04-17 12:22:11 |
|  4 | /store_offers.php  |       3 | 2019-04-17 12:22:41 |
|  5 | /store_offers.html |       2 | 2019-04-17 12:23:04 |
|  6 | /faq.html          |       1 | 2019-04-17 12:23:22 |
|  7 | /index.html        |       3 | 2019-04-17 12:32:25 |
|  8 | /news.php          |       2 | 2019-04-17 12:32:38 |
+----+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

You might simply write:

```
SELECT page_url, user_id, COUNT(*) AS visits 
    -> FROM web_log 
    -> GROUP BY page_url ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

And get the following results:

```
+-------------------+---------+--------+
| page_url          | user_id | visits |
+-------------------+---------+--------+
| /index.html       |       1 |      3 |
| /news.php         |       1 |      2 |
| /store_offers.php |       3 |      2 |
| /faq.html         |       1 |      1 |
+-------------------+---------+--------+
```

But what does the `user_id` column represent? If you think about it, its contents are completely random.

You need to either include it in the group_by clause, or exclude it from your select (or otherwise include it in an aggregate function like `count`, `min`, `max`, etc.)

So for me, I need to include the other non-aggregate columns in my select:

```
select `events`.`listing_id`, `events`.`date`, `events`.`listing_name`, count(*) as number_sold 
from `events` 
where `events`.`date` >= "2020-07-14"
group by `events`.`listing_id`, `events`.`date`, `events`.`listing_name`
order by `events`.`date` asc
```

In my situation, this gives the expected dataset.